# Как сохранять историю выполненных заданий в JasperReports Server?

Tags: jasperreports

Я хочу сохранять историю выполненных заданий по построению отчётов в JasperReports Server (по умолчанию отображаются только выполняющиеся задания, а после окончанию выполнения они исчезают). Как я заметила, когда задание планировщика по построению отчёта выполняется, это задание присутствует в таблице `jasperserver.jireportjob`. Но после того, как задание закончилось, [оно сразу же исчезает из этой таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760862/%D0%9A%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-jireportjob). И, как я понимаю, для того, чтобы история выполненных заданий сохранялась, нужно отменить вызов какого-то триггера/функции, выполняющего/выполняющей очистку этой таблицы. Как это сделать?